# CSS rule not working (width: auto)

Tags: html, css

I put within my css file the following rule :

```
.navbar-form .select2-container ul.select2-choices,
.navbar-form .select2-container ul.select2-choices .select2-search-field input {
  max-width: auto !important;
}
```

Unfortunately, the rule is barred and in addition of that, this message was displayed :

> Invalid property value

In brief, what value can I put ?

Comment: `max-width` can't be `auto`. It has to be some value. Maybe what you want is `width:auto`, or `max-width:none`

Comment: Please post more code. There isn't enough here to determine whatever it is you are trying to accomplish. "Auto" isn't a valid "Max-width" value.

Comment: i think i copied the entire rule. So i'd likethat  input text  takes the entire width

Comment: if you want it to take the entire width then it is width:100%;max-width:100%

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are the valid values

> none
>     - The width has no maximum value.
>
> length
>     - See [length](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length) for possible units.
>
> percentage
>     - Specified as a [percentage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/percentage) of containing block's width.

Src: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/max-width

Comment: Thanks for using an MDN reference instead of w3schools. A much better resource IMO

Answer (score 1):

Max-width cannot be set to "auto". See [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_max-width.asp), and scroll down to valid Property Values. For max-width, these include:

> **none** : No maximum width (the default)
>
> **length** : Define maximum width in px, cm, etc.
>
> **percent(%)** : Define maximum width in percent of the containing block.
>
> **initial** : Sets the property to its default/initial value.

Typically, `max-width` can be used together with a `width` property. So you can say "I want my `div.container` to have `width:100%;`, but I also want to 'cap' that width at 1024px, by also setting `max-width:1024px;`."

This is especially useful for controlling your styles across different devices/breakpoints.